# Get-Content -Raw does not compare correctly in an if statement

Tags: powershell

Why doesn't this work?

```
$text = Get-Content "E:\out.txt" -Raw
Get-Content C:\inetpub\web_empower\App_Data\file.txt -Tail 30 -wait | % {
  $_
  if($_ -eq "$text") {
    break
  }
}
```

`$text` takes a value from `out.txt`, something like `hub_33`. Inside the if statement `if($_ -eq "$text")`, `$text` is not getting the value stored above. `$text` itself is acting as a string not as a variable.
I want the `$text` value which is `hub_33` inside the if statement. But `$text` inside the if statement is acting as a string, not as a variable carrying the value `hub_33`.

Comment: Do you want the bottom 30 lines up to where it finds $text, or to exclude the lines matching $text, or something else?

Comment: $PS = ((get-date).ToLocalTime()).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
$PS2 = ".txt"
$RES = $PS + $PS2
$TES = Get-Content "E:\out.txt" -Raw

Get-Content C:\inetpub\web_empower\App_Data\$RES -Tail 30 -wait | % {$_ ; if($_ -eq "Client_334") {break}}
what i want is i have stored a value inside $TES variable which takes value from the out.txt file 
 Get-Content C:\inetpub\web_empower\App_Data\$RES -Tail 30 -wait | % {$_ ; if($_ -eq "$TES") {break}} >>  if($_ -eq "$TES") >> i want $TES value inside if statement which is not happening

Comment: $RES is working fine but $TES is not working 
 $RES value is like 2021_10_03.txt which is working 
 $TES value is like file_334

Comment: $TES is a variable containing a value stored 
which has to be called inside if statement

Comment: Can you please edit that into your question and check the formatting. It's not readable at the moment.

Comment: $text = Get-Content "E:\out.txt" -Raw
Get-Content C:\inetpub\web_empower\App_Data\file.txt -Tail 30 -wait | % {
  $_
  if($_ -eq "$text") {
    break
  }
}

$text takes a value from out.txt something like hub_33
if($_ -eq "$text") >> inside if statement "$text" is not getting the value stored above $text itself is acting as a string not as a variable

so my question is why $text variable  is not calling its value 
are there any problems in syntax 
what's wrong in my code

Comment: Why are you saying `get-content -raw`?

Comment: yes get-content -raw

Comment: my problem is simple why $text value which is jes_336 is not replaced inside if statement

Comment: You mean `jes_336\r\n` because of the `-raw`.

Comment: problem solved 
there were some spaces in out.txt
i removed those spaces and it works

Answer (score 1):

Get-content -raw includes the line ending \r\n or 0D 0A.  So that will never be equal to the current line of file.txt, that doesn't include the line ending.  It should work without -raw.

```
'line' | set-content out.txt
$text = get-content out.txt -raw
$text | format-hex


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   6C 69 6E 65 0D 0A                                line..
```